# Open inbox or achievement buttons in new tab goes to "Page not found" on non-logged in sites

Tags: bug, top-bar

If you're on a logged-in site, clicking the inbox and achievement buttons on the top right opens a popup. Right-click > Open in new tab goes to the respective tabs on your profile, e.g. https://stackexchange.com/users/7230627/todd-sewell?tab=inbox

If you're on a non logged-in site, the popups still work fine, but opening them in new tabs gets you to broken links like these: https://stackexchange.com/users/?tab=reputation